# Why did my install all of a sudden get really slow?

Tags: performance

It is just running really sluggish, and slow... Kinda reminds me of when I work on Windows computers that are full of Virii.. Any ideas or suggestions? Let me know if you need any more information.

Also, my computer usually runs pretty fast, I have Linux Mint, and Windows installed on the same PC and they run fine...

Comment: Did you make any recent system changes? It's hard to tell what the cause might be unless you can tell us more about what you were doing before you had performance issues.

Comment: Good guestion and there is nothing that I can think of. If I do I will add it to my post.

Comment: Is the hard drive usage gone up? Plus what are the programs using the most CPU?

Comment: Looking for the same answer too, I've experienced the exact same issue over the last month and couldn't understand why - thought of posting the question myself but have no idea what could be causing it. Initially thought it was compiz so started using unity 2D but the same is starting to happen with it. I tried a live CD and interestingly it zings along and is super fast, I performed an upgrade from 11.04 (which was a fresh install) to 11.10 and thought that may have had something to do with it and was considering a reformat and new install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, user error... in a manor of speaking...

The computer got shoved up against a shelf on the side where the air blows out, and was not allowing for sufficiant cooling of the computer... Not sure why this only impacted Ubuntu, and not Linux Mint... Odd... but as soon as I pulled it back out to its proper place it worked fine.